# Links to texample.net use https but site seems to use only http

Tags: support, hyperlinks

My browser refuses to follow links to [texample.net](https://texample.net/) on the grounds that the site is not available via `https`. But earlier questions link to the site using `https` e.g. [most recent such question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/707594/problem-with-tikzpicture-and-matrix-for-flowchart).

The warning suggests to me something bad has happened and I'm being directed to an imposter, say. But I'm guessing the site has automatically changed `http` to `https` and the reality is less sinister: the site simply hasn't made the leap to `https`.

Is it possible to figure out whether the site made the changes or the `http` is an imposter? There's no edit history, but I wouldn't expect any if the url was altered as part of an automated mass change.

Comment: isn't that site one of Stefan's? ping him in chat and remind him to renew the certificate

Comment: These will be the originally posted URLs, even the automated site-wide `http://tex.stackexchange.com` to `https://tex.stackexchange.com` updates were done as visible edits (e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/335607/revisions).

Comment: @cfr I renewed the certificate, so your browser won't complain now. It expired 3 days ago; I normally track expiry using LetsMonitor.org but was too busy traveling this time to update in time. Thank you for the notification!

Comment: @StefanKottwitz Ah, thanks! Apologies for the noise.